# chowning the host's bound `docker.sock` inside container breaks host docker

Tags: macos, docker, ubuntu, docker-in-docker

On a vanilla install of Docker for Mac my `docker.sock` is owned by my local user:

```sh
$ stat -c "%U:%G" /var/run/docker.sock

juliano:staff
```

Even if I add the user and group on my `Dockerfile`, when trying to run DinD as me, the mount of the `docker.sock` is created with `root:root`.

```sh
$ docker run -it --rm \
    --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    --group-add staff \
    --user $(id -u):$(id -g) \
    "your-average-container:latest" \
    /bin/bash -c 'ls -l /var/run/docker.sock' 

srw-rw---- 1 root root 0 Jun 17 07:34 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Going the other way, running DinD as root, `chown`ing the socket, then running commands **breaks the host docker**.

```sh
$ docker run -it --rm \
    --volume /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
    --group-add staff \
    "your-average-container:latest" \
    /bin/bash

$ chown juliano:staff /var/run/docker.sock
$ sudo su juliano
$ docker ps

[some valid docker output]

$ exit

$ docker ps

Error response from daemon: Bad response from Docker engine
```

I've seen [people](https://forums.docker.com/t/mounting-using-var-run-docker-sock-in-a-container-not-running-as-root/34390) reporting chowning as the way to go, so maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Questions:

- Why does the host docker break?
- Is there some way to prevent host docker from breaking and still giving my user permission to the socket inside docker?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that when you are mounting the volume the owner UID/GID is set to the same as in the host machine (the --user flag simply allows you to run the command as a specific UID/GID and it doesn't have impact on the permission for mounted volume)

The main question is - why would you need to chown? Can't you just run the commands inside the container as root?

Comment: 1) Sorry but no, like I showed in the question, the UID/GID are set to root:root upon mounting. 2) Why: if I write files to volumes as root they get written as root to the original filesystem, preventing me from sharing writeable resources between docker and non-docker processes.

Comment: 1) Let me further clarify. I think the behavior I'm seeing is specific to Docker for Mac. I just tested this in Ubuntu and ownership is indeed carried through when mounting. I imagine this might be due to mere cgroups in Ubuntu vs virtualization on Mac. I do need to support both platforms.

Comment: I just tested the ownership of files created in a mounted volume and this is what I experience:

When you mount the volume to container the owner of the folder inside the container will be the user that you assign using --user flag. When you create a file inside that folder from the container in the host file system it will be owned by the user that is owner of the docker.sock

Comment: But the question still remains - what's the actual need for you to use docker.sock inside you container? If you could provide a specific example of what is not working I might test and see what's the underlaying issue might be

Comment: Ownership test: I'm seeing mixed behavior here with ownership actually. In macos, my docker.sock gets mounted as owned by root regardless of --user. My application folder gets mounted with the --user as owner.

Comment: Why mount docker.sock: I'm using nix inside docker to build docker images, which I will then load into the host's docker. Docker in Docker is not an uncommon use-case as far as I've seen through googling, I've read the DinD nickname for it a bunch of times. I can't build them in macos directly as rn nix will build a broken container with darwin binaries. I do the same in Jenkins to prevent the nix installation from "contaminating" the host.

Comment: @Juliano Yes - DinD is a pretty common thing especially in CI/CD context, but I am a bit confused about the statement, that building the images from Mac will build broken images with darwin binaries.That part doesn't make sense to me, unless you are compiling the binaries on your host and then copying them to the image? If so, I would just suggest you use multi-stage image, where you can use Linux based image to build your binaries and then copy them to your final image (one without all the dependencies for building the binaries) https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/

Comment: Why I get darwin binaries: I'm using [nixpkgs](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#ssec-pkgs-dockerTools-buildImage) to build images, not docker, and apparently it's not compatible with macos yet (or properly compatible). I get non-elf binaries when I try to run anything in the built images.

Comment: I'd suggest you use https://hub.docker.com/r/nixpkgs/nix image to build your binaries and the copy them from the build image to the end-image...
Example gist: https://gist.github.com/karlisabe/e3f9cfb83291768dc325778cf58d82ae

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I won't mark this as the answer tho as the original 2 questions remain open.